# Assembly Microsoft.Owin nao encontrado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, owin

Em meu projeto estou usando a biblioteca OWIN para autenticação de usuários. Ja instalei o pacote, porem quando executo o projeto me é retornado o erro:

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma de suas dependências. A definição do manifesto do assembly localizado não corresponde à referência do assembly. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Se alguem puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstale uma versão mais atual do Microsoft.Owin, está versão é de e janeiro de 2014. Instale a versão 3.0.1.

```
Update-Package Microsoft.Owin
```

**Obs:** As vezes ir em Import and Export Settings, e dar um Reset all settings resolve o problema

Comment: Fazer um `Clean Solution` e apagar todas as pastas `packages`, `obj` e `bin` também é uma pratica comum de forçar recriar os binários.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema e a correção foi:

```
Build -> Clean Solution, and Build -> Rebuild Solution
```

Antes de publicar. apaguei todos arquivos e depois

```
Build -> Publish
```

Funcionou legal pra mim (VS2017 / IIS 7)